# How to transform the returned exception from AWS Java Lambda Function to API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a http endpoint name - HE. This 'HE' endpoint connected with Lambda function 'L'.

So HE-->L

On some situation 'L' return Exception in this format :

{
  "errorMessage": "Name John Doe is invalid. Exception occurred...",
  "errorType": "java.lang.Exception",
  "stackTrace": [
    "example.Hello.handler(Hello.java:9)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
    "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
    "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
    "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)"
  ]
}

And the same returned by the 'HE' as is.

How I can use the Integration Response(AWS API Gateway) at 'HE' so it should only display the following :

{
 "errorMessage": "Name John Doe is invalid. Exception occurred..."
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your set-up correctly.  I'm assuming that your API Gateway is calling your Lambda function and that your Lambda function is returning the string you gave as an error object.  In that case...

Add a new method response to your method.  Set HTTP status of the method response to the HTTP status code you want to return, maybe 400 for this case.

Add a new integration response to your method.

Set the "Lambda Error Regex" of the integration response to a regex which will uniquely identify the error.  ".*Name .* is invalid.*" should work for this case.

Set the "Method response status" to the HTTP status of the method response (400 in my example).

Hit save.  Expand the integration response.  Expand "Body Mapping Templates".  Click "Add mapping template".  Set the Content-Type to "application/json" (or whatever content type you want).  Click the check box.

In the mapping template editor box, add a mapping template like this...

```html
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{"errorMessage" : "$input.path('$.errorMessage')"}
```

If I misunderstood your set-up and your API Gateway is calling an HTTP endpoint, then the approach is similar, but the terminology of some of the terms changes.